# Could someone explain the significance of this headwear?

Tags: clothing, chasidut-hasidism

There is a [viral video](https://www.facebook.com/alfie.southion/posts/10212053446596625) making its way around social media, this is a guy asking a question to some young Hasidic men.

This relates to an offensive nickname for a football team, despite the obvious annoying behaviour of the person who took this video, could someone explain the white head wear that the young man in the middle is wearing, is this a *shtreimel*?

It appears that he is being led by his friends and he is carrying a cane of some description, could someone explain why he is dressed differently to other Hasidim that I see usually?  Is this something related to Bobover Hasidism?

I'm genuinely interested, and before anyone asks, *yes*, I understand the (*bad*) joke.

Comment: Tottenham Hotspur Football Club are known by certain rivals as "The Yids" - the person taking the video is asking the group of young men if they are "you boys going [sic] Millwall" [ie. are they going to watch the upcoming Tottenham Hotspur vs Millwall FC football match]. It is a xenophobic and  silly joke and probably frightened the guys, but there is a lot of speculation about the dress of the guys, hence my original post (and the link to the video in the fifth and sixth words of my post).

Comment: Why the -1? +1 to bring it back to an even 0.

Comment: Tottenam is also known to supporters as the Yids because Tottenham was once a Jewish area, the colors are blue and white and most Jews traditionally supported either totenham or arsenal.

Comment: white spodik, not streimel

Comment: @kouty - do you have any more information on his white trousers, the cane, why he was being held by his friends arms and why he wasn't looking up?

Comment: either streimal or spodik but it looks fake and is being worn by a young kid. was this on purim?

Comment: @ClintEastwood Tottenham [is still a Jewish area](https://goo.gl/maps/am5ye6w6hAu), and is increasingly becoming so.

Comment: For the uninitiated reader of [Clint Eastwood's comment](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/4534/clint-eastwood): Arsenal and Tottenham are adjacent to Stamford Hill which has the largest Jewish presence in the UK.

Answer (score 3):

Groups like this are a common sight in chassidic communities on and around [Purim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim). It is an accepted custom of Purim to make fun even of things one would not make fun of the rest of the year. The subject of the joke here is chassidic rebbes, who often walk accompanied (or supported – many rebbes are elderly and frail) by one or more helpers, and will avert their vision to avoid seeing unholy sights. The white socks and knickers, shiny coat, and walking stick with silver handle are typical equipment of rebbes, while the hat is an obviously fake shtreimel (again standard gear) which is white to further poke fun of the fact that many rebbes wear white editions of chassidic clothing. No actual rebbe wears a white shtreimel.

*Source: over a decade of living among chassidim.*